# How can I jump sole parent nodes in neo4j to flatten a tree-like structure?

Tags: neo4j, tree, cypher, parent-child

I have a graph in a neo4j database where the nodes follow a parent/child relationship in a tree like fashion. Without modifying the graph, I would like to create new relationships that "jump" unnecessary parents (defined as a parent who only has one child). I.E. I want to add the blue lines in the second picture as new relationships (we'll say "SkipParent").

[image: current capture]

[image: desired outcome]

How would I go about doing this? I know that I can match a line of 3 consecutive nodes by doing something like this:

```
MATCH (a:Node)<-[:Parent]-(b:Node)<-[:Parent]-(c:Node)
WHERE c.nodeIndex = b.nodeIndex + 1 and b.nodeIndex = a.nodeIndex + 1
RETURN a,b,c
```

But adding a relationship to these would just jump a single parent. Given the graphs could theoretically have rather long sequences I would rather not create and delete these jumps until some arbitrary number either. Is there a way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    MATCH (n)-->()
    WHERE NOT SIZE( (n)--() )=2
    CALL apoc.cypher.run('
     WITH {n} as n
     MATCH p=(n)-[:parent*1..]->(m)
     WHERE NOT SIZE( (m)--() )=2
     RETURN m
     ORDER BY length(p)
     LIMIT 1'
     , {n:n}) YIELD value 
    WITH n, value.m as parent
    CREATE (n)-[:super_parent]->(parent)
```

There are a couple of components to this question.

First, we have to identify the nodes we want to target. Intermediate parent nodes have 2 connections: one to a child and one to a parent. Super parents will have more than 2 relationships (except Node 0 which is the terminal parent and only has one incoming relationship), and child leaf nodes will only have 1 relationship. As such, use a conditional to remove all nodes with exactly 2 relationships: `WHERE NOT SIZE( (n)--() )=2`

The second task is to use a variable length path to find the child's super parent: `(n)-[:parent*1..]->(m)`

Variable length paths will return all results that meet the criteria, so the third task is to only return the shortest path. This is accomplished using the 'length' function and apoc.cypher.run to limit the results to just the shortest path. Without this criteria, the variable length path will return not just the super parent, but also the super parent's super parents all the way up to Node 0.

Lastly, we create a new relationship between the child node and its super parent. `CREATE (n)-[:super_parent]->(parent)`

The example graph was recreated with the following code:

```
    CREATE (a {name:0})<-[r:parent]-(b {name:1});
    CREATE (a {name:2})<-[r:parent]-(b {name:3});
    CREATE (a {name:4})<-[r:parent]-(b {name:5});
    CREATE (a {name:6})<-[r:parent]-(b {name:7});
    CREATE (a {name:8})<-[r:parent]-(b {name:9});
    CREATE (a {name:10});
    CREATE (a {name:11});
    CREATE (a {name:12})<-[r:parent]-(b {name:13});
    CREATE (a {name:14});
    CREATE (a {name:15});
    CREATE (a {name:16})<-[r:parent]-(b {name:17});
    CREATE (a {name:18});
    CREATE (a {name:19});
    CREATE (a {name:20})<-[r:parent]-(b {name:21});
    MATCH (n {name:1}), (m {name:2})
    CREATE (n)<-[r:parent]-(m);
    MATCH (n {name:3}), (m {name:4})
    CREATE (n)<-[r:parent]-(m);
    MATCH (n {name:5}), (m {name:6})
    CREATE (n)<-[r:parent]-(m);
    MATCH (n {name:7}), (m {name:8})
    CREATE (n)<-[r:parent]-(m);
    MATCH (n {name:8}), (m {name:10})
    CREATE (n)<-[r:parent]-(m);
    MATCH (n {name:6}), (m {name:11})
    CREATE (n)<-[r:parent]-(m);
    MATCH (n {name:11}), (m {name:12})
    CREATE (n)<-[r:parent]-(m);
    MATCH (n {name:12}), (m {name:14})
    CREATE (n)<-[r:parent]-(m);
    MATCH (n {name:6}), (m {name:15})
    CREATE (n)<-[r:parent]-(m);
    MATCH (n {name:15}), (m {name:16})
    CREATE (n)<-[r:parent]-(m);
    MATCH (n {name:16}), (m {name:18})
    CREATE (n)<-[r:parent]-(m);
    MATCH (n {name:5}), (m {name:19})
    CREATE (n)<-[r:parent]-(m);
    MATCH (n {name:19}), (m {name:20})
    CREATE (n)<-[r:parent]-(m);
```

Comment: Thanks Julie! I had to modify line 6 to deal with the root parent having 2 children, but otherwise this did the trick.